# Jackson XML Serialization XMLElementRef name

Tags: xml, serialization, jaxb, jackson, fasterxml

Hello I need to configure fastxml.Jackson Serializer to work exactly as a default JAXB Serializer.

I have the following case with two classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "elA")
public class A {
    @XmlElementRef
    public Collection<B> getBs() {
        return this.bs;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "elB")
public class B {

}
```

My Object Mapper config looks like this:

```
XmlMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
objectMapper.registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);

objectMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT,true);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE,false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.CLOSE_CLOSEABLE, true);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT);

JaxbAnnotationIntrospector jaxbAnnotationIntrospector = new XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector(objectMapper.getTypeFactory());
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(jaxbAnnotationIntrospector);
```

I need to configure ObjectMapper for Jackson Serializer to produce the following XML

```
<elA>
   <elB></elB>
   <elB></elB>
</elA>
```

But I get this:

```
<A>
    <bs></bs>
    <bs></bs>
</A>
```

How should I configure Object Mapper to get the expected result? Thank you.

I cannot change neither classes nor annotations since this is part of framework.

The only things I can influence are ObjectMapper and Jackson configurations.

Comment: I have a framework with the classes A and B and corresponding annotations. I'm not able neither to change classes nor their annotations. I need to configure ObjectMapper or jackson Configurations that it recognizes the annotations in the same way as JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "elA")
public class ElA{
@XmlElementRef
public Collection<B> getElB() {
    return this.elb;
}
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "elB")
public class ElB{

}
```

Comment: I cannot change the structure of the classes A and B since they are part of the legacy code.

Comment: change from @XmlRootElement(name = "elB") to @XmlElement(name = "elB")

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot change any annotations or classes because they belong to the legacy code.

Comment: The only thing I can change is ObjectMapper or Jackson configurations.

Comment: if you dont want to change something how could you expect result to be changed.

Comment: bdw how there is 2 root element in one xml

Comment: I have a framework with the classes A and B and corresponding annotations. I'm not able neither to change classes nor their annotations. I need to configure ObjectMapper or jackson Configurations that it recognizes the annotations in the same way as JAXB.